# Dynamics CRM processing lot of data via Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I need to insert and delete a lot of data in crm with web api. If I do it with a simple insert, it takes very long.

Is there another way to insert into the crm database?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `Dynamics CRM` or whatever they rebranded it as (CRM 365 or something)? If so, no, the only supported method of inserting is via the API. And it's slow. Especially batch deletes. You can use [ExecuteMultiple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load) but you are still limited to 1000 batch size.

Comment: Yes, I mean Dynamics CRM. Thats really bad, I need to delete the whole table and insert it again on a daily basis.

Comment: I added both tags because who the hell knows what MS wants to call these applications today. I offered to burninate/consolidate the dynamics tags on stackoverflow meta but it's not worth the effort of going through the gauntlet of meta commenters to get traction. Is there any way you can get a local table for tracking changes? Then only insert/delete the differences? This is how I have usually solved this issue in my CRM integration days. It is easier and more efficient to read the API for updated records and compare to a local table.

Comment: The table I want to insert comes from another system and gets calculated every day. There is unfortunately no chance to get the changes only.

Comment: Try with batching and ExecuteMultiple request. I have not had a good experience doing batch deletes though... but they may have improved things in the last 2 years.

Comment: [executeMultiple](https://debajmecrm.com/2019/02/11/crud-operations-using-executemultiple-in-dynamics-365/) with batches of 1000 is the standard approach. Have you considered the possibility of using a [virtual entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/virtual-entities/get-started-ve)? Or if you want to get really crazy, perhaps investigate the feasibility of deleting the entire entity and recreating it programmatically (of course I have not done this, nor can I recommend it.)

Comment: How many records total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could use [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load), create a collection of request (CreateRequest or UpdateRequest) add it to the ExectuteMultipleRequest and send it to Dynamics 365, there ir a limit of processing batches (200) to increase it could call to product support

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Dynamics 365 Web api endpoint, use the batch operation approach to submit bulk request in a single request. Refer the below link for more details

[Execute batch operations using the Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api)